# Unity Touch Input

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, input, touch

I have built a small game by unity. In which, when the player touch the screen a pin spawns. The problem I am having is, when I touch the screen, instead of one, two pin spawns at a time. I used this code-

```
 if(Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        Spawnpin();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the code inside `TouchPhase.Began` or `TouchPhase.Ended` so that it will be called once only and will only be called again when the touch is released and pressed again. Deciding between `TouchPhase.Began` and `TouchPhase.Ended` depends on whether you want the touch to register immediately when it is pressed or after it is released.

```
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {   
            if (Input.touchCount == 1)
            {
                Spawnpin();
            }
        }
    }
}
```